# Under what conditions does the limit f(g(x)) exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Under what conditions does

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x))
$$

exist? I've seen examples like this from Khan that show you can use one-sided limits and discontinuities to break a lot of expectations around limits and still have an answer:

[image]

So what's the rule for when this composite limit exists?

Comment: A subcase: if $g(x)$ only takes on values in some set $S$ (could be finite, could be infinite, could be connected, could be disjoint, and $g(x)$ can oscillate between different values in $S$ as often as it wants) and $f(x)$ is constant on $S$, then $f(g(x))$ is constant, so its limits always exist, regardless of how bad $f$ and $g$ are.

Comment: There is not really a theorem which classifies every possible way that this limit could exist---$f$ and $g$ can be very bizarre, but the composition can be nicely behaved.  The "usual" theorem given is something like "If $f\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = b$ and $\lim_{y\to b} g(y) = c$. then $\lim_{x \to a} g(f(x))$ exists, and is equal to $c$."  Sometimes authors will say something little more specific, e.g. assume that $g$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm aware of that rule, but it seems more limited, not covering cases like this which use one sided limits.  That rule narrows in on the case where the limit = c, I'm more interested in the general question at which a does the limit exist.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: note that in your comment, the "theorem" as stated is false! Consider $f(x)=b$ identically, and $g(y)=c$ if $y\ne b$ while $g(b)=c+1$.

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed, but notice that I "hedged", knowing that I was probably going to miss a hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ D_f $ and $ D_g $ be respectively the domains of the functions $ f $ and $ g$.

Let $ B\subset D_f $ and $ A\subset D_g $.

Assume that $ a $ and $ b $ are adherent points of $ A $ and $ B $ .

Then, If

$$\lim_{x\to a,x\in A}g(x)=b$$
$$\lim_{x\to b,x\in B}f(x)=L$$
and
$$g(A)\subset B$$
Then
$$\lim_{x\to a,x\in A}f(g(x))=L$$
where $ L $ is an adherent point of $ f(B)$.

If you want the left limit at $ a $ and the right limit at $ b $, you will take

$$A=(-\infty,a)\cap D_g$$
$$B=(b,+\infty)\cap D_f$$

Comment: Is it possible to describe this just in terms of calculus without "adherent points" which seems to come from topology.  I am learning calc right now, I often see things explained in terms of "neighborhoods" and other topology but usually have veered away. I am familiar with epsilon delta notation though.  Is there a way to explain this without topology?

Comment: generally, the domains are intervals, and the adherent points where we compute limits are the extemities.

Comment: Extremity means the minimum and maximum extremas?

Comment: @bgcode The extremities of $ (a,b) $ are $ a $ and $ b $.